# Modify python var using linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, command

I coded some basic Tkinter text labels using Python, but I want to modify the text that is inside the label using a command in the Linux terminal.

This is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
from tkinter import *
outputText = 'Libre'

root = Tk()

w = 70
h = 50

ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = root.winfo_screenheight()

x = (ws/10) - (w/5)
y = (hs/5) - (h/5)

root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w,h,x,y))

root.overrideredirect(1)

var = StringVar()

l = Label(root, textvariable=var)
l.pack()
l.place(x=10, y=10)

var.set(outputText)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you google "interprocess communication" you will find lots of ways for programs to communicate with one another. Sockets or dbus is probably the most common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many many ways. The first that comes to mind for me is a named pipe (aka fifo). Here's the python code (I'm assuming python3 due to your tkinter import even though your shebang is for python2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk
import os
import stat
from threading import Thread

class FIFO(Thread):
    def __init__(self, pipename, func):
        self.pipename = pipename
        if pipename in os.listdir('.'):
            if not stat.S_ISFIFO(os.stat(self.pipename).st_mode):
                raise ValueError("file exists but is not a pipe")
        else:
            os.mkfifo(pipename)
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.func = func

        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            with open(self.pipename) as f: # blocks
                self.func(f.read())

    def close(self):
        os.remove(self.pipename)

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar(value='Libre')

# pipes the content of the named pipe "signal" to the function "var.set"
pipe = FIFO("signal", var.set)

l = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)
l.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.geometry("200x100")
root.mainloop()
pipe.close()
```

This example creates a pipe named "signal", so anything you write to that pipe gets set in the variable. For instance if you open a new terminal in the same folder and type

```
echo I am a cucumber > signal
```

Then the Label in the tkinter window changes to "I am a cucumber".

You can also access this from any other program or programming language. For instance if you want to send data from another python program:

```
with open('signal', 'w') as f:
    f.write('I am a banana')
```

Named pipes are designed to allow many programs to write to them, but only one program should read the data out.